# How to ask the topic for an exam

Tags: questions

A teacher tells the students that she/he  would conduct an exam. The students want to know the topics for the exam. How should the students ask it?

What are the topics for exam?

What topics are there for the exam?

Or is there a simple way to qsk this question?

Comment: There are many possible ways. "What topics will be in the exam?" "Can you tell us what topics to revise for the exam?" etc. etc.

Comment: What topics will the exam cover?

Comment: And if you're in North America, "What topics will be **on** the exam?" "Can you tell us what topics to **review** for the exam?"